# import error while using python and Django

Tags: python, django

I am making a website using the django api.
Problem is I am getting a weird import error. I have a function in a file which calls another function in another file which in turn calls back a third function in the first file.

Problem is during that third function. When I try to import it I get an error

```
cannot import deletefromS3.
```

A full stack trace is given below

http://dpaste.com/1288190/

Here are the snippets of the two modules:

topichandler.py:

```
from sdbhandler.mediahandler import deleteMediaParent
def deletefromS3(itemid,folder):
itemid=folder+itemid
bucket = connect_s3()
for key in bucket:
    fname=key.split(".")[0]
    if(fname==itemid):
        bucket.delete_key(key)
        return []


def deleteTopic(itemid,parentId='NULL'):
    sdb=connect()
    domain= sdb.get_domain(DOMAIN)
    rootitem = domain.get_item(itemid)
    if(parentId=='NULL'):
          query= 'select * from ' + DOMAIN + ' where itemName()="'+itemid+'"'
          rs = domain.select(query)
    else:
          rs = [rootitem]
    for  item in rs:
          deleteMediaParent(item.name)
          deletefromS3(item.name,'topicsK2/')
          domain.delete_attributes(item.name)
    deleteMediaParent(rootitem.name)
    deletefromS3(rootitem.name,'topicsK2/')
    domain.delete_attributes(rootitem.name)
```

mediahandler.py:

```
from sdbhandler.topichandler import deletefromS3
def deleteMediaParent(parentid):
sdb=connect()
domain = sdb.get_domain(DOMAIN)
query = 'select * from '+ DOMAIN + 'where ' +FIELD_TopicID + ' = "' + parentid + '"'
rs = domain.select(query)
for item in rs:
    deleteQuestionParent(item.name)
    deletefromS3(item.name,'mediaK2/')
    domain.delete_attributes(item.name)
```

There are more dependencies but I cannot post my whole code that would be way too much.
Can I not import from the file from which a method was called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import is impossible because a module has to finish loading before things can be imported from it.
When the `topichandler` module loads, it tries to import `deleteMediaParent` from `mediahandler`. But `mediahandler` tries to import `deletefromS3` from `topichandler`, which triggers another attempt to load `topichandler`. Python catches the infinite loop that’s about to happen and raises an error instead.

Let’s look at this with a simpler example. Here is `foo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

x = 3

from bar import y

print x, y
```

and here is `bar.py`:

```
from foo import x

y = x
```

This gives the same error you got, for the same reason.

Although the best solution is probably to restructure your code into more coherent standalone modules, there is a workaround. You can delay the import by moving it into a function, as in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

x = 3

from bar import y

print x, y()
```

`bar.py`:

```
def y():
    from foo import x
    return x
```

Note that if you run this the `print` will actually be imported twice… again, you probably are better off moving related functions into the same module.

Comment: So I define that common module in a seperate file?

Comment: @SilentPro Yeah, you can do that too.

Comment: Thanks I'm new to python have done most of my coding in java so don't know some of these nerves so to say.